# How to Use If statement inside select in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, if-statement, select

Unable to use `if` statement inside `Select` in **Oracle 12c**

```
SELECT if(2 * 5 = 10, '1', null) AS a 
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: If it existed as you describe it, `if` would be a function or an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `case`:

```
 SELECT CASE 
          WHEN 2 * 5 = 10 THEN '1' -- put the right condition here
          ELSE null
        END AS a 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Another possibility is `Decode`:

```
 SELECT Decode(2 * 5, 10, '1', null) AS a
   FROM DUAL;
```

Please, note that `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF` syntax is *PL/SQL*, not *SQL* one.